# How can I configure the RingBuffer used by ReliableTopic in Hazelcast? I have multiple topics

Tags: java, messaging, hazelcast

I am creating multiple reliable topics in Hazelcast. As I understand from the documentation, it is backed by a ringbuffer. How can I configure the ringbuffer for a topic to suit my needs?
I want to persist only top 100 messages for one topic and entire history for another.

Comment: Don't answer that! I think I got it..

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the reliable topic backing ring buffers by using the prefix `_hz_rb_` in front of your reliable topic's name. For instance; assume that you have a reliable topic with the name `myReliableTopic`. The ring buffer backing this reliable topic will have the name as `_hz_rb_myReliableTopic`. So, you can configure it as below:

```
<ringbuffer name="_hz_rb_myReliableTopic">
    <capacity>100</capacity>
</ringbuffer>
```

You can access this prefix using the `RingbufferService.TOPIC_RB_PREFIX` static field in the application.

Please remind that this prefix is not a part of the public API, thus it is not guaranteed to be kept unchanged in future releases.

Comment: I want to configure OverflowPolicy of my RingBuffer. I want it to behave in a way, so that the RingBuffer backing a ReliableTopic always stores the top 100 messages. It seems, I can set the OverflowPolicy only when I'm adding an element to the RingBuffer, using the addAsync/addAllAsync method. Can I not configure it?

Comment: Have you checked Slow Consumers (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#slow-consumers) for Reliable Topic? Does it work for you?

Comment: This appears to still hold true which is nice. I’m quite surprised the RingBuffer can’t be configured via the ReliableTopicConfig.

Comment: I think you should use the same name, per doc: "You may configure this Ringbuffer by adding a Ringbuffer config with the same name as the Reliable Topic.". See https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.2/manual/html-single/index.html#reliable-topic

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the name same for ReliableTopic & RingBuffer does not work. While getting RingBuffer Object we have to prefix it with _hz_rb_as said by Alparslan Avci ealier is the only solution. Hazelcast document says otherwise but it does not work. Looks like a bug in Hazelcast.

Rakesh